# jQuery incorrect handling of array when URL-encoding object?

Tags: jquery, ajax, urlencode

When passing an object as the `data` to the `ajax` call, I am getting some unexpected results. For some reason, jQuery is adding square brackets to my parameter names if their value is an array. For instance...

```
var obj =
    {
        name: "John Doe",
        courses: [ 1, 2, 4 ]
    };
```

...becomes `name=John+Doe&courses[]=1&courses[]=2&courses[]=4` instead of `name=John+Doe&courses=1&courses=2&courses=4`.

Why is jQuery adding the square brackets?

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/BrHSy/

**Update:**

I expect the above example to produce a string similar to the query string in this example:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form method="GET">
            <input type="hidden" name="name" value="John Doe"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="courses" value="1"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="courses" value="2"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="courses" value="4"/>

            <button>Go!</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Notice that the query string which is produced by the form (www-form-urlencoded) does not have the square brackets.

Answer (score 4):

I found my own answer. It looks like jQuery, when encoding the data using `$.param`, does not specifically `www-form-urlencode` the data. It is serializing it instead. Prior to jQuery 1.4, the results would have been as expected.

The solution for me, then, is to use the traditional logic instead by passing `true`:

```
$.param(obj, true);
```

This results in: `name=John+Doe&courses=1&courses=2&courses=4`

When calling `$.ajax()`, you can set the `traditional` option to `true` to have jQuery encode the data in the traditionally expected manner. It seems that `traditional` should have been the default since jQuery's `ajax` function, by default, uses the `www-form-urlencode` content type. But the end result, when the data is sent to the server, is a malformed `www-form-urlencode`'d chunk of data (according to how HTML forms are handled in general if they have multiple inputs with the same name).

Updated example here: http://jsfiddle.net/BrHSy/1/

Comment: Great, this has been driving me nuts. Setting `traditional:true` to ajax works. But I don't understand your first line `$.param(obj, true);`. What is `obj`?

Comment: Hi @PureW, `obj` is the thing I want to encode, as in the OP.